# How to set a string value in Spinner view..?

Tags: android, string, android-spinner, dropdown

In spinner view values at andoid(i.e..one,two,three),now i selected two,then i change selected value two as string.after i will asign two(string value) as set to one spinner.

Comment: can you explain more on this?

Comment: In spinner view values at andoid(i.e..one,two,three),now i selected two,then i change selected value two as string.after i will asign two(string value) as set to one spinner.

Comment: so have you successfully change the selected value to string ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a spinner, follow this steps

Declare  `Spinner number` 
and `String Number` as global

In `onCreate()`

```
number = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourSpinnerId);
addItemsOnSpinner()
```

Then write `addItemsOnSpinner()`

```
 public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("one");
        list.add("two");
        list.add("three");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        number.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

> How to set a string value in Spinner view..?

If I understand your question correctly, you want to set the selected value (2) as a string right ? You can write in this way

```
Number=number.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

The Number will now holds the spinner item, number as a string.

Comment: john this part i will completed,now my dout is,if you select three means,number = number.getselecteditem().tostring(),number=three,now how i set this number value as first in that spinner list.

Comment: will your data will get from `SQLite` ? If yes I can do for you

Comment: i will get the data directly from server not sqlite.

Comment: can you show the code on how you retrieve the data to spinner ?